# How to check if a PosixPath is a directory or a file

Tags: python, pathlib

With `Path` I can run `path.is_dir()`, how can I do the same thing with `PosixPath`?

Comment: The same way? `PosixPath` extends from `Path`.

Comment: I was clearly being dense. Thank you. Please don't downvote as this question hasn't been asked yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I do the same thing with `PosixPath`?

Exactly the same way. `PosixPath` *extends* `Path` so has all the underlying methods:

```py
Python 3.9.0 (default, Oct 12 2020, 02:44:01)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pathlib, os

>>> pathlib.PosixPath("/").is_dir()
True

>>> os.system("touch /tmp/aFile.txt")

>>> pathlib.PosixPath("/tmp/aFile.txt").is_dir()
False

>>> pathlib.PosixPath("/tmp/aFile.txt").is_file()
True
```

Comment: Wow. I was doing `isdir()` and freaking out about how it wasn't working. Thank you.